# Is "sliced the tires" what one would say?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> The next morning someone had scratched my car and sliced the tires.

Is "sliced the tires" what one would say?

Comment: The phrase *slashed the tires* is more common, at least in America.

Comment: [Here's the relevant usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sliced+the+tires%2Cstabbed+the+tires%2Cslashed+the+tires%2Csliced+the+tyres%2Cstabbed+the+tyres%2Cslashed+the+tyres&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csliced%20the%20tires%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstabbed%20the%20tires%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslashed%20the%20tires%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslashed%20the%20tyres%3B%2Cc0) showing that it's the same with BrE ***tyres*** as AmE ***tires***.

Answer (score 2):

Cars typically get "scratched" (could be accidental) or "keyed" (always intentional).

Tires typically get "slashed" (always intentional), resulting in being "flat" (which could also be accidental on its own).